# RAR command line - Exclude all directories

Tags: rar

I have the following structure :

FOLDER :

- file1
- file2
- file3
- subfolder1

  - file1.1
  - file1.2
- subfolder2

  - file2.1
  - file2.2

I would like to create an archive with the files in the root only (excluding all subfolder nevermind their name)

I tried :
rar a archive.rar FOLDER
and
rar a -r- archive.rar FOLDER

Both case, the archive is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By documentation it should be `rar a -r archive.rar D:\path\to\FOLDER\*`

Comment: Yes I should have specified the path
But still doesn't work

Comment: Actually, it works ! I guess my path was a bit wrong ;) Thx